# How can avoid that pictures go behind the side navbar?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to build my first website. I made a side nav bar and when I put the pictures into the body, these go behind the navbar. How can i prevent this behaviour and distribute them correctly without overlapping with the navbar?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #555855;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- The sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#news">Mylogo</a>
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#contact">Projects</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>



<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/367/267">

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/367/267">
<br>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1032/367/267" alt=""> </div>

<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1036/367/267" alt=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have four closing div tags that don't have matching opening div tags.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to contain the images within a div and the navbar within another div.  Then you'll have to modify the width of each div within the main container so they dont have the ability to overlap.

For instance:

```
#maincontainer{
width: 100%;
}

#sidenav{
width: 20%;
}

#images{
width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion Sean!

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a little bit.

- Wrapped images in a div and styled it.

**Hope this is what you are looking for:**

```css
 body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.rightbar {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.rightbar img {
    width: 48%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #555855;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/styles.css" />
    
    <title> Portraits</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- The sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#news">Mylogo</a>
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#contact">Projects</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<!-- Page content -->
+

         <div class="rightbar">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/367/267" >

          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/367/267">
     <br>

        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1032/367/267" alt="">
        
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1036/367/267" alt="">
         </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it fixed :)